# Orfeo toolbox on QGIS Mac

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, otb-applications

I have been trying to download the latest version of Orfeo Toolbox (version 8.1.2) so I can use it on my pre-existing QGIS project  (I have a Mac with an Apple silicon chip, and I have downloaded QGIS 3.30 on my computer). I tried every one of the installation instructions, and I keep getting errors.

When I tried the instructions from the website, it wanted me to use a docker image, but I don't think it's possible to get that image off docker and onto QGIS without either of them being on a Virtual machine (side note, I have no idea what a virtual machine is, nor how to use or get one).
I tried some instructions from http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/OTB_Plugin_installation but the terminal kept saying the file didn't exist when I had literally just downloaded it and opened up the terminal window afterwards. And when I tried it a second time, nothing happened (not exaggerating).

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: OTB is not available for Apple silicon. The instructions you link to explicitly state "*This package was compiled using an Intel processor, and won’t be compatible with ARM processors found in the most recent MacOS computers.*"

Comment: So if you want to use OTB, you'll have to follow their recommendation to use the Docker image. Just install [Docker on your Mac](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install), it doesn't need to be a virtual machine.  Follow the OTB instructions to get the docker image (from a commandline `docker pull etc.`), then follow the instructions on the OTB docker page (https://hub.docker.com/r/orfeotoolbox/otb) for MacOS. I have no idea how you would use the docker OTB with QGIS though.